# System.Data.DataTable.Row.Select() Issue

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I'm having some difficulty setting a value on several TextBoxes during the `_SelectedValueChanged()` event of the `ComboBox`.

My form has one `ComboBox`, and four other `TextBox` fields underneath it. Basically, I want to update the value of the text fields, when the `ComboBox.SelectedText` is changed.

So far my code looks like this:

Properties:

```
        this.cmbTopic.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", this.hCAliasDataSet, "Items.Topic", true));
        this.cmbTopic.DataSource = this.hCAliasDataSet;
        this.cmbTopic.DisplayMember = "Items.Topic";
        this.cmbTopic.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(81, 14);
        this.cmbTopic.Name = "cmbTopic";
        this.cmbTopic.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(199, 21);
        this.cmbTopic.TabIndex = 0;
        this.ToolTip1.SetToolTip(this.cmbTopic, "Add a new Topic");
        this.cmbTopic.ValueMember = "Items.Topic";
        this.cmbTopic.SelectedValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cmbTopic_SelectedValueChanged);
```

Event:

```
    private void cmbTopic_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sQuery;            

        sQuery = "Topic = '" + cmbTopic.SelectedText + "'";

        // Set the textboxes according to selected Topic value
        DataRow[] dr = hCAliasDataSet.Tables["Topics"].Select(sQuery);

        for (int i = 0; i < dr.Length; i++)
        {
            this.txtFields_1.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[i]["Description"]);
            this.txtFields_2.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[i]["Family"]);
            this.txtFields_3.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[i]["Options"]);
            this.txtFields_4.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[i]["Group"]);
        }
     }
```

When the program is running, I go to change the `ComboBox` value and nothing appears to be happening?

Comment: Do you know at what point the code is failing? Is the event firing? Does `dr` return *any* DataRow objects?

Comment: Have you stepped into the code with the debugger to see if 1) the event handler is being fired and 2) if the query is returning any data?

Answer (score 0):

Your are getting result in data Roiw which always gives only one row.dataRow[] is basically an array object of DataRow and here your are looping through its element.

You should know how many elemnts it is giving then made a check of it before filling text box instead doing looping.

Try this out

```
    if ( dr.Length > 1)
       {
        this.txtFields_1.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["Description"]);
        this.txtFields_2.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["Family"]);
        this.txtFields_3.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["Options"]);
        this.txtFields_4.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["Group"]);
    }
```

and also make sure that elements are not null or empty.You can provide a defalt value to the textboxes by this

```
    this.txtFields_1.Text =(string.IsNullOrEmpty(drRow["Family"].ToString())) ? "No data" : Convert.ToString(dr["Family"]);
```